# Remove section header from a beamer theme (Singapore)?

Tags: beamer, header-footer, themes

I like everything about the beamer theme Singapore except:

1. The centering of the frame title
2. The navigation symbols that remain at the bottom
3. The sections in the header

The first two are easily solved by

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][left]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
```

I still can't find a solution for the third though. `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}` gets rid of the sections in the header but dumps the nice shading. So my question: how do I get rid of those pesky sections (e.g., the "foo bar baz" below) in the header without dumping the shading?

[image: exampleframe]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A quick way disabling the navigation header containing the sections while keeping the shading:

```
\renewcommand{\insertnavigation}[1]{}
```

or

```
\def\insertnavigation#1{\relax}
```

Comment: Definitely worked. Mysterious. No idea how I could have poked around and come up with that on my own. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

I found the use of either `\renewcommand{\insertnavigation}[1]{}`
or
`\def\insertnavigation#1{\relax}`
produced unsightly white space above the shading when used in a block so as to only affect certain slides such as the first one:

```
{
\renewcommand{\insertnavigation}[1]{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\frame{\titlepage}
}
```

[image: Unsightly white space above slide shading]

I solved this by extracting the shading code from the Singapore theme, removing the vertical adjustment and inserting it *in lieu* of the headline template:

```
{
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\pgfuseshading{beamer@headfade}}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\frame{\titlepage}
}
```