# Beamer slide with no bullet!

Tags: beamer, navigation

I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\begin{document}
    \section{Section 1}
    \begin{frame}
        Slide 1
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        Slide 2
    \end{frame}
    \section[]{}
    \begin{frame}
        Slide with no section!
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In the third slide, I have no idea why there is a black bullet in the navigation bar; also if you click on the first bullet, it takes you to the third slide, which is wrong. Any reason why?

[image]

Comment: Don't use the section command with empty short argument. Compare `\section[]{}` with `\section[foo]{faa}`.

Comment: It does not work :)

Comment: Maybe `\frametitle{}` could help you.

Comment: It does not do exactly what I want. I use multiple title page like here:  {https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147392/multiple-titlepages-in-a-beamer-presentation}

Comment: So, maybe starat another `\part{}` to clean the navigations (I hope).

Comment: @Sigure: Sorry, \section[foo]{faa} does not work either. I had to run it 3 times so it appeared. What is \part{} btw?

Comment: To update the navigation bar you have to compile twice. It is the same idea for table of contents.

Comment: So, I think what you want is a way to clear the header locally.

Comment: Not removing the navigation bar, I want the navigation bar to be there, while all bullets are empty.

Answer (score 3):

(solution from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132281/14757))

Is this what you want?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\title{A main title}
\author{Main Author}

\begin{document}
{
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\pgfuseshading{beamer@headfade}}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\frame{\titlepage}
}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{frame}
  Slide 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  Slide 2
\end{frame}

%% second part

\title{A secondary title}
\author{Main Author and others}

{
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\pgfuseshading{beamer@headfade}}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\frame{\titlepage}
}

\section{Section 2}

\begin{frame}
  Slide 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  Slide 2
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you want the navigation for the second part starting at left, simply start a new part after the second author/title data:

```
\title{A secondary title}
\author{Main Author and others}
\part{}
{
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\pgfuseshading{beamer@headfade}}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\frame{\titlepage}
}
```

Comment: It is a good answer, but not exactly what I was asking for. I wanted the navigation bar to be there, while all the bullets are empty. +1 for the use of \part.